# How to install libraries without composer in drupal 8

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8

In drupal 8, I am encountering modules that require libraries to be installed by Composer. However, I was wondering if I could skip the composer part and just install the libraries by hand.

Would I ever be able to do this?

(I have never gotten Composer to work)

Comment: Composer is an important part of the modern PHP ecosystem. It brings considerable benefits. I recommend asking about how to get it to work (it's not hard) instead of fighting against it.

Comment: To ask about the problems you've had getting Composer to work? Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extract the library at `/libraries`.

For colorbox, you should have `root/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js`

But this way you miss the main purpose of composer cause it won't be possible to update all the dependence automatically.

Comment: Hello, I need to install commerceguys/addressing library. I have downloaded and uploaded library files to vendors/commerceguys/addressing in drupal. I have cleared cache but still this library is not installed on drupal. Can you please tell me how can I install this library without composer. I can't run composer because i am on a shared hosting.